# clang-format: Use custom style if file doesn't exist

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I want to format code using a custom style if .clang-format doesn't exist. Is there any way to do so?
I used --fallback-style but it fails.

```sh
clang-format -i --style=file --fallback-style="{BasedOnStyle: google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 100}" a.cpp
```

It raises an error:

```
Invalid fallback style "{BasedOnStyle: google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 100}
```

Comment: Have you tried capitalizing `Google`?

Comment: Default style names are not case-sensitive @SparkyPotato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is a command line option to use another style if `.clang_format` file doesn't exist.

The option -fallback-style does work only with predefined styles, which are `llvm`, `chromium`, `mozilla`, `google`, `webkit`, `gnu`, `microsoft`. Also there is `none` to skip formatiing. You can use `-fallback-style=google` for example.

However I would suggest other ways. Here is how `clang-format` finds files:
it checks for `.clang-format` and `_clang-format` files in all directories from the one which contains a file you want to format, then the parent of this directory, then the parent of this, and so on to the root directory. So there are two options:

1. Manually check if configuration file for `clang-format` exists.
2. Put your custom fallback style in root or home directory, so that clang-format finds your file in case it can't find it in a project